# How can I disable horizontal scrolling in a Tkinter listbox? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

Say in Tkinter you have a listbox of a certain size within a window. Then let's say you add a string to that listbox that is larger than that size. If you highlight this element and drag to the side the listbox will automatically "scroll" itself so that you can see the full element. Is there anyway to disable this short of running a thread that repeatedly attempts to set the scroll to 0?

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root)
listbox.insert("end", "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example")
listbox.pack()
root.mainloop()
quit()
```

Comment: I have a temporary solution now if nobody can provide something more elegant. Assigning `root.after(50, reset_scroll)` to the root window and having reset scroll do the same thing after it calls .xview(0) on the box works.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Added example to the question, if you click and drag to highlight the element the listbox will automatically scroll. I wish to disable this functionality.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to remove this feature? It seems like users of your program might want to be able to see long entries.

Comment: This probably highlights an underlying problem in my design but I'm making a game that is interacted with through 3 listboxes. The listboxes will never have elements longer than they should be when packed into a window that is 800x600 - the minimum size. I've put separators between the elements in the listboxes for organizational purposes. The separators are the character ("━"*100) so that they take up the width of the box. The problem arises however that I have an element in the box longer than the width, which then causes this previous problem. https://i.imgur.com/FCVBFcq.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-scrolling is triggered by the mouse leaving the listbox while the button is pressed. Perhaps the simplest solution is to prevent that behavior by creating your own binding that returns "break":

```
listbox.bind("<B1-Leave>", lambda event: "break")
```

Note: this will also prevent the vertical auto-scrolling. If you want to keep the vertical auto-scrolling than you'll have to write a more complex function that will only return "break" if the mouse is to the left or right of the listbox.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. This solves the problem, I didn't realize you could chain together B1 and Leave like that.