# Replace predefined key binded functions in tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I've created a listbox and I want the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>`Right`</kbd> arrow keys to move up and down the listbox (respectively) but the default key binded functions of <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> keys are to move the list left and right like a horizontal scroll.

How do I replace the function of the left and right keys?

Could the code look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *                                                
window=Tk()                                                          
list_b=Listbox()                                                     
                                                                     
list_b.insert(END,'line 1')                                          
list_b.insert(END,'line 2')                                          
list_b.insert(END,'this is a really really really long line')        
list_b.insert(END,'line 4')                                          
                                                                     
list_b.grid()

list_b.disable_horizontal_scroll() #some method to disable horizontal scroll                                                           
list_b.bind('<Right>',move_down) # has the same effect as the up arrow key                                    
list_b.bind('<Left>',move_up)    # has the same effect as the down arrow key                                  
list_b.focus()                                                       
                                                                     
                                                                     
window.mainloop()
```

I've already tried `list_b.bind("<B1-Leave>", lambda event: "break")` from [How can I disable horizontal scrolling in a Tkinter listbox? (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565987/how-can-i-disable-horizontal-scrolling-in-a-tkinter-listbox-python-3) but it does not disable horizontal scrolling.

**NOTE-**

I'm not trying to replace the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys, I asked this question as it is a segment of a larger, more complex code and the given snippet of the code is merely an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is `return 'break'` at the end of your function. Since I dont know your functions, I made my own for this purpose, like:

```
def move_down():
    try:
        idx = list_b.curselection()[0]
        list_b.selection_clear(0,'end')
        list_b.selection_set(idx+1)
        list_b.activate(idx+1)
        return 'break'
    except IndexError:
        idx = 0
        list_b.selection_clear(0,'end')
        list_b.selection_set(idx)
        list_b.activate(idx)
        return 'break'

def move_up():
    try:
        idx = list_b.curselection()[0]
        list_b.selection_clear(0,'end')
        list_b.selection_set(idx-1)
        list_b.activate(idx-1)
        return 'break'
    except IndexError:
        idx = list_b.size()
        list_b.selection_clear(0,'end')
        list_b.selection_set(idx-1)
        list_b.activate(idx-1)
        return 'break'
# Binding
list_b.bind('<Right>',lambda event:move_down()) 
list_b.bind('<Left>',lambda event: move_up())
```

Comment: so does adding 'break' work for any replacement key binding?

Comment: @WiredDifferently `'break'` prevents the default behaviour from happening

Answer (score 0):

In the functions bound to the event, you need to return the string "break" to prevent the default behavior from happening.

Second, while you can certainly define the `move_up` and `move_down` commands in python to mimic the behavior of the up and down keys, you can also directly call the internal tk functions used by those keys. That's the solution I'll present here:

```
def move_down(event):
    event.widget.tk.call("tk::ListboxUpDown", event.widget, 1)
    return "break" 

def move_up(event):
    event.widget.tk.call("tk::ListboxUpDown", event.widget, -1)
    return "break"
```