# Python Tkinter Listbox Back Forward Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox and I printed some contents with it. I want to put a back and forth button, as I press the button, it goes back and forth in the indexes and this selection appears in the listbox.
For example, 0 index is selected in the photo. When I press Forth, I want it to come to 1 index.
For this, I did research and analyzed the sample codes, but did not have the idea that I could not find the result.

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

my_frame = Frame(root)

my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient=VERTICAL) 

list = Listbox(my_frame, width=85, height=20, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)

for i in range(50):
    list.insert(END, str(i)+".index")

my_scrollbar.config(command=list.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

my_frame.pack()
list.pack()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace predefined key binded functions in tkinter Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013830/replace-predefined-key-binded-functions-in-tkinter-listbox)

Comment: The listbox has methods for changing the selection. All you need to do is call them. Have you read through the documentation on the listbox? It's not clear why you need our help when the answer is provided in the standard documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you'd like 2 buttons that allows you to cycle forward and backwards through the indexes.

So below is your code modified that allows you to visibly cycle through the listbox by using the GUI.

**(EXPLANATION BELOW)**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack()

my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(my_frame)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listBox_0 = tk.Listbox(my_frame, width=85, height=20, yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set, selectmode='single')
listBox_0.pack()

my_scrollbar.config(command=listBox_0.yview)


def backButtonFN(my_frame):
    curselection = listBox_0.curselection()
    indexLB = curselection[0]
    indexLB = indexLB - 1
    if indexLB > 0 or indexLB == 0:
        listBox_0.selection_clear(0, last='end')
        listBox_0.selection_set(indexLB)
    else:
        None
pass

def forwardButtonFN(my_frame):
    curselection = listBox_0.curselection() #current selection method
    indexLB = curselection[0] #get value of index
    indexLB = indexLB + 1 #add 1 to current value
    listBox_0.selection_clear(0, last='end') #delete old selection
    listBox_0.selection_set(indexLB) #select new index
pass

backButton = tk.Button(my_frame) 
backButton.configure(text='BACK')
backButton.pack(anchor='s', side='left')
backButton.bind('<1>', backButtonFN, add='' )


forwardButton = tk.Button(my_frame) 
forwardButton.configure(text='FOWARD')
forwardButton.pack(anchor='s', side='right')
forwardButton.bind('<1>', forwardButtonFN, add='' )

for i in range(50):
    listBox_0.insert(END, str(i)+".index")

listBox_0.selection_set(0) #activate first index
```

Initially you called your listbox `list`, which is a big no-go as it can cause issues in terms of syntax later on down the line, so I changed the name of the Listbox to `listBox_0`, so this is your new `Listbox` as you originally intended.

once I did that, I created 2 functions for each of the forward and backwards buttons, I also had to rearrange the code to allow it to `<bind>` correctly.

I started off by making the first index active, that essentially will give me a value for `curselection()`, I then took that value, turned it into an integer I could play with, then each time you press the button, it will turn that extracted index, add one to it, then remove the previous selection and then add the new updated selection with `indexLB`

Then the same process for `backButtonFN` except this time, I am deducting 1 instead of adding, and then making sure it doesn't continue to go back once it hits 0.

I've also changed your configuration for `listBox_0` to `selectmode='single'` to allow you to select one item at a row, you can disable this if you'd like to select multiple.

It can definitely use some tidying up as the pro's may immediately see, but I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, exactly the code I wanted :)